# Android: Test retrofit success,failure

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Android testing. All I am trying now is new [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) with Junit4. the thing I go till now is Espresso is for ui testing and with junit we can do logical testing. So I am trying Junit to test my **retrofit code**:

```
protected String signIn(String emailNumber, String password) {

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Constants.API_URL).build();
    RetroInterface retroInterface = restAdapter.create(RetroInterface.class);

    retroInterface.signIn(emailNumber, password, new Callback<SignInPojo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(SignInPojo signInPojo, Response response) {
            if (signInPojo.getError()) {
                Snackbar.with(getApplicationContext()).text(signInPojo.getMessage())
                        .textColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400)).show(SignInActivity.this);
                result = "successerror";

            } else {
                Log.d("Json", signInPojo.getName());
                result = "Successfully Signed In";
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LenderActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("RetroError", error.toString());
            Log.d("RetroUrl", error.getUrl());
            result = "failed";
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

with these test Class:
**SignInActivityJunit.java**

```
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class SignInActivityJunit extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SignInActivity>{
    private SignInActivity signInActivity;

    public SignInActivityJunit() {
        super(SignInActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        signInActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkSignIn_Success() {
        String result = signInActivity.signIn("99929992", "aaaaaaaa");
        assertThat(result, is(equalTo("success")));
    }@Test
    public void checkSignIn_SuccessButError() {
        String result = signInActivity.signIn("99929992", "aaaaaaaa");
        assertThat(result, is(equalTo("successerror")));
    }@Test
    public void checkSignIn_Fail() {
        String result = signInActivity.signIn("99929992", "aaaaaaaa");
        assertThat(result, is(equalTo("success")));
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Now these all cases failed because on debugging I saw that they are not waiting for the network to return call(As per my guess). They are skipping **success** and **failure** methods.
So the question is.. how to make unit test wait till retrofit returns the request. Or is there any other efficient way to test these network connectivity.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question, but I think a more correct way of testing web services would be to mock the server and request, or to actually test the UI with espresso.

In first case, with `jUnit`, you don't create an actual request, but rather a mocking one that will return a predifined result (the result could be read from a file). Here you could test that the conversion of response to your model classes is successful, if you have any.

In the second case, with `Espresso`, test the actual thing on device, like open LoginActivity -> retrieve the login/username fields -> type text -> click on Login button. And as expected result here you could put some controls from the main activity (the one that redirects you after a successful login)